# Should Web Developers upgrade to Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, upgrade

I am a web applications developer stuck working on a Windows machine.  Today I got an update notification asking me to upgrade Internet Explorer to version 8.  I previously had IE 8 installed during the beta, but uninstalled it due to inconsistencies between it's 'compatibility mode' and a stand-alone version of IE 7 (very weird, albeit 'fringe', javascript/css errors).

So my question is, have those inconsistencies been worked out by now?  If I test a site in compatibility mode, how confident can I be that that's exactly how it will appear/work in IE 7?  Do you think it's 'safe' for a web developer to upgrade to IE 8 at this point in time?

Comment: I think you should stick to standards and not care which browser your user has. That's the only right way. I think browser wars are over, they all now comply to standards... heh? Utopia?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install IE8, you need to be able to check pages in IE8 after all.
To check with older versions, you can install [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage). It saves you from bothering with virtual machines.

Comment: IETester seems to work for 99% of problems. If I recall correctly, I did have one or two cases where I had to go to a real IE6.

Comment: On some installations, IETester gave me some odd JavaScript popup when loading a page, while actual IE6 did not.

Comment: Another big reason to upgrade is security issues with older IE. IE8 is much safer, at least as per articles that I see on internet.

Comment: This question was about a developer's perspective. Security is not much of an issue if you only use IE to view your own web pages.

Answer (score 6):

The best advice I can give is that you keep a few Virtual Machines with IE7 and IE6.  IE8 has been very inconsistent for me as well, crashing every now and then.  Compatibility mode seems to work at least in my sites, so that part looks ok.

Answer (score 5):

I'm currently developing web sites for IE6, IE7, IE8, Firefox, Safari, Opera, and Chrome all on the same machine.

I use IE8 to test both IE8 and IE7 rendering (using the Developer tools that are including, you can switch the browser between IE8 and IE7 rendering modes...not to mention switch between Quirks and Compatibility mode for each browser).

To get back to IE6 I use the Beta of [Microsoft SuperPreview](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8e6ac106-525d-45d0-84db-dccff3fae677&displaylang=en) (if you haven't seen it, check it out...they're going to offer Firefox and Safari rendering to it last I checked)

Answer (score 3):

You can always run different versions of [Internet Explorer in Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en) to emulate different environments. That's what we do, at it really works.

Microsoft even released this for free (see above link).

Answer (score 3):

After trying IE8's Developer Tools (press F12) and seeing how nice it is, i can say that its a must to upgrade, and you have many other ways to test on previous versions as previous answers listed.

A similar [Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en) was available for download for IE7.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had any problems with compatibility mode.  I upgraded to IE8, although we still have a test machine that runs IE7.  I also use [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage), which is a FANTASTIC tool.

Answer (score 1):

I went with IE Collection and love it.

http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm

Comment: Is there somewhere else to download this? I keep getting small parts of the file.

Comment: I tried IE collection too - but I found that I couldn't type in text boxes in previous versions - anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is using a multiple IE installation as provided here: http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone else running Windows and not in a corporate environment that filters such things is *also* getting that same update notification.

So, if your users are mostly using company computers where IT departments control IE upgrades, sticking with IE7 on your primary machine (and testing in IE8 in a virtual or other machine) would likely be the best option.

Otherwise, you should move with the majority of your users and either use a virtual machine with IE7 for backward-testing, or use the compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should be developing on whatever browsers are most popular for your audience. If you anticipate your readers are going to be using IE 8, then you should use IE 8.

Obviously you should test in everything, but you should give more focus to what your users are most likely to use.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's worth it for the built-in Developer's Toolkit. (press F12 to see)

Have you considered installing Virtual PC (free) or VMWare and running IE7 in a VM?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a tool like jQuery for your client-side programming, in theory "all" of the compatibility testing has already been done for you.  They have enormous test suites to ensure this.

Comment: No, that won't work at all. jQuery does not provide complete coverage of the space. In real-world applications, you do enough JavaScript, HTML, and CSS outside of jQuery to cause all kinds of things to go wrong in IE6.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately. According to a post on Ajaxian, IE7 users are upgrading to IE8, but IE6 users aren't. Which I guess makes sense--if you skipped IE7, why would you go to IE8?

Comment: I'm in a different situation. Our intranet has approved browsers, so I won't have to develop to IE6, thank God.

Answer (score 0):

**HO MY GOD YES!**

IE8 is a really good product by Micrsoft. Not only it's fast (not as fast as it should be, but it's good enough), but it ripped off all of the features Firebug has. It also contains the rendering engine of IE7, so you are really not loosing anything, only winning.

Press F12, and you will be able to choose how to display the page: IE7, IE8 or some middle thing which I never understand. You can also force the web browser to render in IE7 mode by adding this to your HTML code (taken from http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/06/10/introducing-ie-emulateie7.aspx )

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

I have also this to say: the sites I build usually don't have display problems under IE8 and look the same as FF3, Opera, Konqueror, Chrome etc... It's actually a good browser.